# PaDEL-Descriptor on command line

Tags: javascript, java, bash, fingerprint

I have trouble running in command line

```
java -jar -Xmx20G ~/PaDEL-Descriptor/PaDEL-Descriptor.jar 
-removesalt -standardizenitro -standardizetautomers 
-fingerprints *name fo fingferprint* 
-dir ~/series_of_ligand.smi 
-file  ~/CHEMBL206_IC50_all-Descriptors/RESULT_*name fo fingferprint*.csv
```

*name fo fingferprint* is select fingerprint type (actually i need to get all 12 fingerprint)

my problem is whatever I select difference fingerprint, the result always as pubchem.

How can I run all fingerprint type from command line?

Comment: Are fingerprints saved in a file? What is the file name with extension?

Comment: @Inian you mean output? Based on this code, it will save as 
"RESULT_*name fo fingferprint*.csv"

Answer (score 0):

PaDEL-Descriptor jar reads the Descriptors.xml file to calculate the descriptors and fingerprints and by default only for PubchemFingerprinter the value is true. So, you have to change

```
(<Group name="Fingerprint">
        <Descriptor name="Fingerprinter" value="false"/>
        <Descriptor name="ExtendedFingerprinter" value="false"/>
        <Descriptor name="EStateFingerprinter" value="false"/>
        <Descriptor name="GraphOnlyFingerprinter" value="false"/>
        <Descriptor name="MACCSFingerprinter" value="false"/>
        <Descriptor name="PubchemFingerprinter" value="true"/>
        <Descriptor name="SubstructureFingerprinter" value="false"/>
        <Descriptor name="SubstructureFingerprintCount" value="false"/>
        <Descriptor name="KlekotaRothFingerprinter" value="false"/>
        <Descriptor name="KlekotaRothFingerprintCount" value="false"/>
        <Descriptor name="AtomPairs2DFingerprinter" value="false"/>
        <Descriptor name="AtomPairs2DFingerprintCount" value="false"/>
  </Group>)
```

value="false" to value="true" in the descriptors.xml file given along with PaDEL Descriptor zip file.